# linear combination of infinitely divisible random variables II

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I have a question that repeats the question I found here:

If X and Y are real valued random variables with infinitely divisible distributions, does aX+bY also have an infinitely distribution (a,b∈R). I've seen this stated in several places as obvious, but I have only seen the proof in the case that X and Y are independent. Does anyone know where I can find the proof if we don't assume independence?

The answer was:
I doubt that is true in general. Counter example: Let W1
be a standard normal random variable, and
W2=W1, if |W1|≤1
W2=−W1, otherwise
Then W2
is also a standard normal r.v., but W1+W2
has a finite support, and is not constant, therefore not infinitely divisible, according to
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiowYfs3srKAhXEMyYKHaM1DskQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.abo.fi%2Ffak%2Fmnf%2Fmate%2Fgradschool%2Fsummer_school%2Ftammerfors2011%2Fslides_rosinski.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE_2G83w4nq7gqDM5xvP3pt8c281A&cad=rja

However,

According to

https://books.google.com/books?id=zBZqDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=%22linear+combination%22+%22infinitely+divisible%22&source=bl&ots=bWYkYPGvw5&sig=ACfU3U3IYtQG1VPv3lMFqP3UqR5xzYQZ6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiru8zt0vvhAhUMn-AKHRTRCsEQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22linear%20combination%22%20%22infinitely%20divisible%22&f=false

The book "Random and Vector Measures (Series on Multivariate Analysis)" p.66

aX+bY does be ID

Can you pls help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly typeset math expressions. Also see [Markdown](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10992#10992) formatting, in particular, to avoid excessively long URL hyperlink display.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has standard normal distribution and $Y=X$ when $|X| \leq 1$ and $-X$ when $|X|>1$ then $Y$ also has standard normal distribution and $X+Y$ does not have an ID distribution. This is because it is  a bounded random variable and it is not a constant.

Comment: I knew about the example you provided. However, in the book "Random and Vector Measures (Series on Multivariate Analysis)" p.66, we do have that each linear combination of infinitely divisible random variables is also infinitely divisible.
Do you know corresponding conditions on linear combinations of infinitely divisible random variables to correct this issue?
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Also: Theorem 3.2 of Stochastic Pocelsses and Their Applications 6 (1978) 139-151.

Comment: There is no way you can assert that linear combinations of ID random variables are ID. What is true is linear combinations of $\{X_i:i \in I\}$ are ID if $\{X_i:i \in I\}$ is an ID process (which means all finite dimensional distributions of the process are ID). It is not enough to assume  that each individual $X_i$ id ID.  @AlbertV

Comment: Is it possible to have different definitions of ID? E.g., as defined by Levy and then  linear combinations of ID random variables are ID? Or the published results are incorrect? Also in this context, Section 9.7: "A non-infinitely divisible random vector with infinitely divisible linear combinations of its components", the book "Counterexamples in PROBABILITY" gives "It remains to be shown that any linear combination α1Χ1 +α2X2, α1,α2 ∈ has a distribution which is infinitely divisible".

Comment: The question is what is being considered as ID. For example if we say $(X_n)$ is ID is is usally understood that all finite dimensional distributions are ID, not just that each $X_n$ is ID. Trying to prove that linear combinations of random variables each of which is ID is also ID is simply ridiculous. Individual distributions don't say much about joint distributions or distributions of linear combinations.